# Ending of TYPO3 TypoScript conditions - Changes in V9 and above?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I'm working on a TYPO3 website that I started with V6 and I'm now updating to V10 via V9.

At the moment I'm changing my TypoScript conditions to the new Symfony syntax and found that I have used 4 different endings of conditions:

```
[end]
[END]
[global]
[GLOBAL]
```

Will all these endings still work in TYPO3 V9 and above?

I have searched the reference, but did't find a definite answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/TypoScriptSyntax/Syntax/Conditions.html#the-syntax-of-conditions):

> If `[ condition ]` is TRUE, then the TypoScript in the middle would be
> parsed until `[GLOBAL]` (or `[END]`) resets the condition.